# use std::find to find a std::tuple in a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

So I have a vector of tuple coordinates made with the following code:

```
vector<tuple<int, int>> coordinates;
for (int i = 0; i <  7; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
      coordinates.push_back(make_tuple(i, j));
   }
}
```

I'm trying to fill the board up with either 'x', 'o', or '.' with the following:

```
void displayBoard(vector<tuple<int,int>>& board, vector<tuple<int,int>>& p1, vector<tuple<int,int>>& p2){  // prints out board
  cout << "  a   b   c   d   e   f   g\n";  // top row
  for (int i = 1; i < 43; i++){
    if (i % 7 == 0) {
      if (find(p1.begin(), p1.end(), board[i])) cout << "| x |\n";
      else if (find(p2.begin(), p2.end(), board[i])) cout << "| o |\n";
      else cout << "| . |\n";
    } else {
      if (find(p1.begin(), p1.end(), board[i])) cout << "| x ";
      else if (find(p2.begin(), p2.end(), board[i])) cout << "| o ";
      else cout << "| . ";
    }
  }
}
```

my **int main** looks as follows:

```
int main() {
  vector<tuple<int, int>> coordinates;
  for (int i = 0; i <  7; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
      coordinates.push_back(make_tuple(i, j));
    }
  }
  vector<tuple<int,int>> p1 = {make_tuple(0,1)};
  vector<tuple<int,int>> p2 = {make_tuple(3,1)};
  displayBoard(coordinates, p1, p2);
  return 0;
}
```

I used (0,1) and (3,1) as test coordinates to see if the code would run. Long story short, I wanted to use std::find to find if a tuple coordinate was chosen by either p1 or p2 and format the outputted string accordingly. So if if `std::find_if(p1.begin(), p1.end(), make_tuple(2,2))` was true to put fill the cell with an 'x' for example. The problem is I get the following error when compiling:

`error: could not convert    ‘std::find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tuple<int, int>*, std::vector<std::tuple<int
, int> > >, std::tuple<int, int> >((& p2)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<std::tuple<int, int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<int, int> > >(), (& p2)->s
td::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<std::tuple<int, int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<int, int> > >(), (*(const std::tuple<int, int>*)(& board)->std::vector<_
Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::tuple<int, int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<int, int> > >(((std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> >::size_type)i))))’ from ‘__
gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::tuple<int, int>*, std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > >’ to ‘bool’`

So the question is if i can use std::find_if to find an std::tuple in an std::vector. And if not how can you find a tuple in a vector.

Note: I included: iostream, string, tuple, vector, and algorithm and am using namespace std.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find -- see Return value

Comment: thanks for the link, still get a similar error using std::find_if though

Comment: I didn't say anything about using `std::find_if` (that page is about both `std::find` and `std::find_if`), I said read the Return value section, because you seem to be confused about what `std::find` returns.

Comment: ah i see, iterator not a boolean thanks again

Comment: @Dor-Ron: please don't edit the code already in your question - it removes the context necessary for Sam and Benjamin's feedback to make sense to other readers.  If you want to post code you've tried to fix, do so as an update at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @Dor-Ron: "*ah i see, iterator not a boolean thanks again"* - that's right... the docs Benjamin links above have an example program at the bottom - note the `!= std::end(v)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is not searching for the tuple in the vector. Your search is just fine.

Your issue is that `std::find` returns either an iterator to the found sequence member, or the ending iterator value.

Your code assumes that `std::find`() returns a `bool` indication that the value has been found. This is not true. `std::find()` returns an iterator. Either the iterator to the found value, or the ending iterator value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `find()` versus `find_if()`. Both `find()` and `find_if()` behave identically in this respect. Besides, you just made it worse. `find_if`()'s third parameter is a lambda or a function object, not a value. Your initial use of `find()` was correct. Your problem was not handling the return value correctly. Reread my answer again.

Comment: ah i see, returns an iterator not a boolean my bad thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_if` as follows:

```
int main()
{
vector<tuple<int, int>> coordinates;
coordinates.push_back(make_tuple(0,1));
coordinates.push_back(make_tuple(2,3));

auto t = make_tuple(2,3);

auto it = std::find_if(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end(), [&t](const auto& item) {
    return std::get<0>(t) == std::get<0>(item)
           && std::get<1>(t) == std::get<1>(item);
    });

    if(it!=coordinates.end())
      cout << "found" << endl;
}
```

It returns an iterator to the found sequence, or the end iterator if it hasn't found the element you are looking for.